# When is CanExecute called?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

In the demo, I have a button to toggle a bool field `isAsking`. I create a command which can execute only when `isAsking==true`.

Once I press the Toggle button, `okButton.IsEnable` changes immediately, which indicates the command finds the change of `isAsking`.

I feel very confused why the command object notices the change of a field. When `CanExecute` will be called?

Although writting WPF application for some time, I'm new to WPF Command. Please give an explanation to this case and if possible, point out some related articles or blogs (I've already read too many articles talking about cut/paste command).

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" x:Name="mainWindow" >
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Name="okButton" Content="Ok" />
        <Button Content="Toggle"  Click="Button_Click_1"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Code-behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private bool isAsking;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        CommandBinding cb = new CommandBinding();
        cb.Command = okCommand;
        cb.CanExecute += CanOKExecute;
        cb.Executed += cb_Executed;
        mainWindow.CommandBindings.Add(cb);
        okButton.Command = okCommand;
    }

    private RoutedCommand okCommand = new RoutedCommand("ok", typeof(MainWindow));


    void cb_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       
    }

    void CanOKExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.CanExecute = isAsking;
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        isAsking = !isAsking;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I try to search for "the CommandManager detects conditions" and reach [this exellent article](http://northhorizon.net/2012/better-commands-in-wpf/).

By examining .NET Framework source code, the author finds that the `CommandManager` doesn't detect conditions by itself, rather than when `Keyboard.KeyUpEvent`, `Mouse.MouseUpEvent`, `Keyboard.GotKeyboardFocusEvent`, or `Keyboard.LostKeyboardFocusEvent` occurs, it will reevaluate CanExecute method.

The article includes other information, but the above part has been enough for me.

Comment: I'm a little aghast at this default behavior. If a form has a lot of controls and the CanExecute methods are suboptimally written, this is a horribly large amount of potentially useless CanExecute evaluations isn't it? Having trouble seeing how the architecture scales?

Answer (score 41):

The technical answer is that `CanExecute` will be invoked whenever the [`CommandManager.RequerySuggested`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.commandmanager.requerysuggested.aspx) event is raised.  According to the documentation, this will be...

> ...when the CommandManager detects conditions that might change the ability of a command to execute.

In practical terms, this just means that you don't need to worry about when `CanExecute` is called: WPF will invoke it when it thinks it is appropriate, and in my experience this will almost always cover your requirements.

The  exception to this is if you have a background task that will cause `CanExecute` to change it's return value based on something that is not triggered by the UI.  In this scenario, you may need to manually force the WPF runtime to re-query `CanExecute` which you can do by calling [`CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.commandmanager.invalidaterequerysuggested.aspx)

Comment: or, if it's a Prism `DelegateCommand` - call `RaiseCanExecuteChanged()` on the `Command` itself.

Comment: @Default true.  Similarly, if it's your own `ICommand` implementation you can manually raise the `CanExecuteChanged` event on the command

Comment: Doyyy.. I completely forgot about that event in `ICommand`.. Here I thought Prism was on to something :)

Comment: Given that you have no control over how often it runs you need to ensure that it does not do a lot of stuff, e.g. don't query a database in it.

Answer (score 9):

`RoutedCommand` contains an event `CanExecuteChanged` which internally hook to the `CommandManager.RequerySuggested` event -

```
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }
```

And `CommandManager.RequerySuggested` event is raised

> whenever changes to the command source are detected by the command
>   manager which is in your case is Window. So, when button is clicked, commandManager raised the RequerySuggested event and hence executed the CanExecute predicate registered for your command.

Also, CommandManager has a static method - `InvalidateRequerySuggested` which forces the CommandManager to raise the RequerySuggestedEvent. So, you can call that to validate your commands too manually.

Answer (score 1):

To expand a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14294738/when-is-canexecute-called#comment19853612_14294916) by Default

Suppose we have the following

```
public class SomeClass : ViewModelBase {
   public ICommand ConnectButtonCommand { get; }
   public SomeClass(){
      //...
      ConnectButtonCommand = new DelegateCommand(ConnectButton_Click, ConnectButton_CanExecute);
      //...
   }
   public DoSomething(){
      //do something that affects the result of ConnectButton_CanExecute
      ((DelegateCommand)ConnectButtonCommand).RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
   }
   private void ConnectButton_Click() {/*...*/}
   private bool ConnectButton_CanExecute() {/*...*/}
}
```

I am working on a UWP app that uses Prism for MVVM. Universal windows platform is very similar to WPF.