# CanExecute breakpoint doesn't allow me to use the application

Tags: c#, mvvm, icommand

I'm currently toying a little with MVVM pattern and trying commands. I find the default way (every Command class needs to implement from `ICommand` interface) quite boring, so I've created a new base class called, wait for it, `CommandBase`. It looks like this:

```
public abstract class CommandBase : ICommand
{
    public virtual bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public virtual event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public virtual void Execute(object parameter)
    {

    }
}
```

Now every command just inherits from this base class and overrides what is necessary. I had a bug in the software, so I've put several breakpoints in my inheriting class and in this base class. Everything seems to work as expected, except one thing - the method `CanExecute` gets fired all the time. If I put the breakpoint inside the method, my application won't even start! **If I delete this breakpoint, everything works again.**

MainViewModel:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase // base implements INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ICommand NavigateCommand { get; private set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        NavigateCommand = new NavigateCommand(this);
    }
}
```

My debugger gets to the constructor, instantiate the Command class and from now on the method CanExecute fires like crazy and I can't even open the application window, because the vs debugger won't let me. In my NavigateCommand I only override `Execute` method and set one property of the MainViewModel, nothing too fancy. `CanExecute` is left intact without overriding.

Just a note, the bug I've mentioned was just a typo of my View, it wasn't related to this issue. After I've fixed it, code works except this thingy.

Can someone provide an explanation why it behaves like this?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14294916/2132796).

Comment: @Herdo, thanks for the link, it's kinda clearer now. If I understand it correctly, the only way to resolve this is to keep this method as short as possible to prevent any bugs and forget about debugging it?

Comment: Yep, it's a 'normal' behavior, that `CanExecute` gets fired a lot.
You shouldn't try to debug in this methods. In case of unknown bugs, turn on the `Common Language Runtine Exeptions` at Debug -> Exceptions...

Comment: Ok, thank you. Post this info from your comments as an answer so I can select it :) I guess I should be very careful what to put inside this CanExecute method...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a 'normal' behavior, that `CanExecute` gets fired often by the `CommandManager`. You shouldn't try to debug into this methods. In case of unknow bugs, turn on the `Common Language Runtime Exceptions` at Debug -> Exceptions... Further information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14294738/when-is-canexecute-called/14294916#14294916).

Answer (score 1):

Can I suggest that, unless absolutely necessary, you don't need to reinvent the wheel here. There are a number of excellent implementations of ICommand out there that you can use.

[RelayCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) is probably the most commonly used, although [DelegateCommand](http://wpftutorial.net/DelegateCommand.html) is also very well implemented, and is the standard ICommand implementation is the Prism framework.

Comment: RelayCommand suffers from the same behavior as I've already tested it out, except it allows an easier usage of the methods. However, it seems that DelegateCommand is using a different method for raising the event, that's great. Thanks for the suggestions, +1 for you as well.