# All ContextMenu Menuitem commands are firing Command.CanExecute() on selectionchange

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a sample app whose view is:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local ="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.Commands"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="Menu">
            <MenuItem Header="M" Command="{Binding MyCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
    </ContextMenu>
</Window.Resources>
<DataGrid x:Name="maingrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" ContextMenu="{StaticResource Menu}"/>
```

My cs code is something like this:

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        VM vm = new VM();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            vm.Items = new BindingList<Entity>();
            vm.MyCommand = new MyCommand();
            InitializeComponent();
            for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                vm.Items.Add(new Entity() { X = i });
            }
            base.DataContext = vm;
            Focus();
        }
    }
    public class VM
    {
        public BindingList<Entity> Items { get; set; }
        public Entity SelectedItem { get; set; }
        public ICommand MyCommand { get; set; }
    }
    public class MyCommand : ICommand
    {
        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("CanExecute Called!!!");
            if (parameter != null && (parameter as VM).SelectedItem.X > 20)
            {

                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false; 
            }
        }
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add
            {
                CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
            }

            remove
            {
                CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
            }
        }
        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
    public class Entity
    {
        public int X { get; set; }
        public int X2 { get; set; }
        public int X3 { get; set; }
        public int X4 { get; set; }
        public int X5 { get; set; }
        public int X6 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now if you start the app and open Output window and kepping changing selected rows, there will be no
"CanExecute Called!!!" on output.This is expected behavior as I expect the commands to fire only if the user right clicks on the row.

Now right click on one row and see "CanExecute Called!!!" appear in output window.

Now keep moving the selection up and down and you will see continuously "CanExecute Called!!!" message comes to output.

I want the command to fire only if rightclicked.

Comment: Calling `CanExecute` doesn't mean firing the command, only that WPF is checking if the command is available in current state or not. This check can be called fairly frequently. See for example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14294738/when-is-canexecute-called

Comment: The checks inside my CanExecute are not that lengthy. However there are 10 or more items on the ContextMenu and this is slowing down the movement when the user is doing an up arrow or down arrow to move around the datagrid. If I fire CommandManager.IvalidateRequerySuggested without having this part :
            add
            {
                CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
            }

            remove
            {
                CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
            }
My menuItem does not get enabled.

Comment: Unfortunately `CanExecute` will be called very frequently and there's not much you can do about it. I suggest not doing any checks in it at all, instead just read a bool field which will be updated in the background when something changes. Alternatively, bind IsEnabled of the menu item to a property and don't use `CanExecute` at all. Though I should also add that disabling menu items is not the best UX practice.