# How do I know the trigger of a command

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a silly question: How do I know the trigger of a command in .NET?

I know the command of a button is called when it is clicked. How do I know when the command of a CheckBox is called? I am guessing it is probably when the Checked value changes, but how can I be sure?

Please explain this to me.

**EDIT**

I am talking about Commands, not events. That was not a typo.

As in following Code:

```
<Button x:Name="TestButton" Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}" />
```

Comment: They are all specified in the control design code. You can know about the events that a control will fire from there.

Comment: If it is a RelayCommand that you are using, you can use IsExecuting property. Have a look here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.mvvm.relaycommand.isexecuting%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: How you defined RefreshCommand?.. there you will find CanExecute... subscribe for this.. you will come to know how it works...

Comment: So there is no other way to know how or when a Control is going to call a Command property? If it is not documented, I will never know when its called? You could at least deduce it from the name of an event. That changed now because a command is always called "Command".

Comment: @AmolBavannavar CanExecute will define whether the command can run or not. The op wanted to know when a command executes.

Comment: @Krishna I want to know what triggers a command.

Comment: well, I would say, the most Obvious one ... :)

Comment: @Muds That is not very scientific or safe approach ;)

Comment: @ElMac A command is triggered by whatever the default action on an object is performed. On a button it will be a click, on loaded it will be when the UIElement is loaded into the visual tree and so on. If you look at ICommand interface you will see an execute method. Whenever the default action performed, the 'execute' gets executed (which is usually hooked upto to a method you definited in your VM)

Comment: Well, the best documentation is probably [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): "`ButtonBase`, `MenuItem`, and `Hyperlink` invoke a command when they are clicked, and an `InputBinding` invokes a command when the `InputGesture` associated with it is performed." - so, work out what base class applies for whatever object you're looking at, and that's the answer.

Comment: Take a look on this answer.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/14300147/4112271 .. Is this thread relevent to your thread..

Comment: possible duplicate of [When is CanExecute called?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14294738/when-is-canexecute-called)