# Notifications for tracked changes in EntityFrameworks DbContext

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am building a Data Entry app using Entity Framework where a user can fill out forms and then Save or Cancel. However I want the Save Button only to be enabled when there is actual data that can be saved to the database.

I know about DbContext.ChangeTracker. However I was not able to find a possibility to get a notification form the context whenever there are changes.

Of couse I could track that manually, but that is tedious and error prone.

**Update**
The App is a WinForms Application

**Question:**
How can I get a notification from the DbContext when it "Is Dirty/Has changes"?

**Update 2**

Maybe this can clarify my Question:

This is what I don't want:

```
using(var ctx = new DbContext()) {
  var foo = new FooEntity();
  ctx.Add(foo);
  RaiseContextIsDirty();  //<-- don't want to do this, this should be automatic
  //.....
  ctx.SaveChanges();
  RaiseContextIsClean();  //<-- don't want to do this, this should be automatic
}
```

What I am looking for is something like this:

```
using(var ctx = new DbContext()) {
  ctx.ChangeTracker.OnDirtyChanged += ContextDirtyChanged;
  var foo = new FooEntity();
  ctx.Add(foo);   //<- fires OnDirtyChanged
  //.....
  ctx.SaveChanges();   //<- fires OnDirtyChanged
}
```

Comment: @Nikita No, It is a Standard WinForms Application

Comment: So thinking about this. You have control over what entities get updated/added/deleted. So if when you do an operation you can post a notification that this has happened. You can do this by overriding the `SaveChanges` method, and then accessing the change tracker to find exactly what has happened.

Comment: @CallumLinington this is exactly what I dont want to do. every time when I add/Update/Delete an Entity also calling some Notification Method ist just tedious and error prone.

Comment: your mentioned functionality, apart from added entities, is what the Context.ChangeTracker.HasChanges() does. for added entities, you'd have to set a flag or something when you actually do set an entity's state to added and not rollback.

Comment: Tedious? I think you will find this is just coding.... It's only a couple of methods, you make sure that they're unit tested. You can't expect everyone to write your code for you....

Comment: If you're using code first, you can let all your entity types inherit from some base type having an event to update the dirty state of your data (it would be very efficient, if the data is not dirty, update it as true, otherwise just do nothing). Some event can be declared to just notify when that dirty state is switched from false -> true, otherwise no need to raise any (for best performance). Then any time `SaveChanges` is called, reset the dirty state (and maybe raise some other event). Believe it or not - any change notification is done inside the ***property setter*** - no magic at all.

Comment: @CallumLinington I think we have a Misunderstanding here. I updated the question with some example code.

Comment: No, reviewed the code, but I still stand by my point. It's not been made by the EF team because it's a concern of the application and to be honest like I said, you have complete control over when entities are added/updated/removed so you can quite easily know when an action as been taken... the change tracker is there to show you explicitly everything that has been done.

Comment: You can use the Event Aggregator pattern as a nice way to raise events.. otherwise just implement the win forms event pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for `DbContext.HasUnsavedChanges` property:

```
public partial class MyDBContext 
{
    public bool HasUnsavedChanges
    {
        get
        {
            try
            {
                return this.ChangeTracker.Entries().Any(e => e.State == EntityState.Added
                                                          || e.State == EntityState.Modified
                                                          || e.State == EntityState.Deleted);
            }
            catch (System.InvalidOperationException)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

In WPF it is enough to set this to `CanExecute` condition of a WPF Command `Save`.

The problem in Windows Forms is that you need to find an event that would fire often enough and disable or enable the button, but not too often. I do not think there is any property observer built in the EntityFramework that would provide such events to you.

You can check `dbContext.HasUnsavedChanges` on every mouse up or key up event on that form or something like that, that is similar to how WPF works internally, see - http://northhorizon.net/2012/better-commands-in-wpf/.

Comment: Not sure about some MVVM framework (such as MVVM Light, ..) in which it may do the automatic raising `CanExecuteChanged` event for you but if it's not the case (no library), you still have to raise the `CanExecuteChanged` event ***manually*** whenever it's suitable (from the user's interaction). If you search for `RelayCommand`, you'll see that it may have raiser method - such as `OnCanExecuteChanged` - and this will be publicly called outside to manually update the UI state.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14294738/when-is-canexecute-called. This is how WPF works. See this article, it could be an inspiration, how to rewrite it to Windows Forms. http://northhorizon.net/2012/better-commands-in-wpf/

Comment: You should not always trust in how CanExecuteChanged is raised automatically. It's mainly based on UI not by data. E.g: If you have some code finding something (like in a Dictionary app), the Speak button should be enabled only when some word is found, otherwise should be disabled, in this scenario the auto-raiser mechanism cannot help you (I had to raise the event manually).

Answer (score 0):

So you could have this overridden implementation of the `SaveChanges`:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
   public delegate void ChangeEventHandler(object sender, ChangeEventArgs e);
   public event ChangeEventHandler ChangeEvent;

   public override int SaveChanges()
   {
       var result = base.SaveChanges();

       var entitiesAdded = this.ChangeTracker.Entries.Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Added);
       var entitiesRemoved = this.ChangeTracker.Entries.Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Deleted);
       var entitiesModified = this.ChangeTracker.Entries.Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Modified);

       ChangeEvent(this, new ChangeEventArgs(entitiesAdded, entitiesRemoved, entitiesModified));

       return result;
   }

}
```

Just create a `ChangeEventArgs` by creating a class that implements `EventArgs`.

Then you should just be able to bind to the event the normal way:

```
ctx.ChangeEvent += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine("Changes happened");
```

### Edit

I have just pulled most of this from MSDN, I haven't got time to test it properly. But I don't see this solution being too far wrong.

### Further Thoughts

The `DbSet<T>` backs onto a `IDbSet<T>` so there is no reason why you couldn't implement your own `IDbSet<T>` and when you implemented your own `Add` function wire the events in. This would follow the same pattern as above.

Then in your `MyDbContext` listen to all this events and consolidate them into 1 event or handle them as they come.

Comment: This would only react when SaveChanged is called - *not* when some entity's state has changed.

Comment: @JensKloster well you can adjust for when you update some entities... But the argument for this is that you're following the unit of work, and you shouldn't have your unit of work around for long... To me I'm not sure what this problem is we're trying to solve.... could be `xy` problem

Comment: If the point of the application is to study entities about to be saved to the database but after they have been added to the relevant `DbSet<T>`s then I could see the point of publishing events on CRUD, otherwise one would only care about when they're saved.

Comment: OP ask: `How can I get a notification from the DbContext when it "Is Dirty/Has changes"?` .. you answer will only work if `SaveChanges()` are called every time some entity changes/added/deleted.

Comment: @JensKloster yes, but like I said it can be adjusted to accommodate other needs, this is the gist, my answer shows a) events, b) change tracker, c) overriding methods on DbContext. I mean we could start going into the decorator pattern or AOP to solve the OP's question.

Comment: @JensKloster I added extra information for the individual `DbSet` changes.