# CommandBindings shortcuts executing twice

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

This is how i have implemented the shortcuts in my wpf app:

```
public static class Shortcuts
    {
        static Shortcuts()
        {
            StartScanningCommand = new RoutedCommand();
            StartScanningCommand.InputGestures.Add(new KeyGesture(Key.S, ModifierKeys.Control));
}

 public readonly static RoutedCommand StartScanningCommand;
}
```

In my xaml view I have this:

```
<Window.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static local:Shortcuts.StartScanningCommand}" x:Name="StartScanningCommand" Executed="StartScanningCommand_Executed" CanExecute="StartScanningCommand_CanExecute"/>    
</Window.CommandBindings>
```

And in the xaml's class:

```
private void StartScanningCommand_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                Scanner.Start();
            }
        private void StartScanningCommand_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            e.CanExecute = AppCurrent.GetPermissionManager().CanScan();
            if (!e.CanExecute)
            {
                AppCurrent.Broadcasts.ApplicationStatusBroadcast.NotifySubscribers(this, new ApplicationStatusEventArgs("You dont have permission to scan", StatusType.Error));
            }
        }
```

But for some reason `StartScanningCommand_CanExecute` execute twice. If I put a `MessageBox.Show` inside the method, the dialog is shown twice.

Any reason why is this happeing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.commandbinding.canexecute(v=vs.110).aspx), as well as [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14300147/1940394), there are two options that I can up up with as to why you're getting the event twice. To know for sure, add event handlers for things, and see which ones get called.

1. It's being called for `PreviewCanExecute` and `CanExecute` events
2. It's being called when the object receives Keyboard focus, and when the mouse is released

However, you are using `CanExecute` incorrectly. `CanExecute` should return `true` or `false` only. The user should be unaware that it's being called. One use that I've seen that helps this make sense is for a menu. If you give it a binding, and it can't execute, the menu item will be grayed out.

So, if the user can click it regardless, then you should have that `MessageBox` in the `Executed` method, not the `CanExecute` method.

Comment: afaik, it doesnt matter if you have any logic inside the CanExecuted as long as you set the property CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs#CanExecute to true or false. I'm  aware that i may not be using it correctly(in terms of design), but that does not justify the reason of why is executing twice.

Comment: See edit. There's a couple reasons I was able to find, but it looks like you'll have to experiment to know for sure.